# How to btrace JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x, java-8, visualvm, btrace

I'm trying to instrument JBoss AS 7 using btrace but can't get it to work. I'm using visualvm 1.3.7 and the btrace workbench 0.6.7 (right click -> "Trace applicaiton..."). I'm always setting the following non-descriptive error.

```
!!! Error occured
!!! Error occured
```

What I tried is setting the following VM options

```
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=com.sun.btrace,com.sun.btrace.annotations
-Xbootclasspath/a:/path/to/btrace-boot-1.2.3.jar
```

but no avail. I am running on Java 8.

Even simple scripts like this don't work:

```
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.println;

import com.sun.btrace.annotations.BTrace;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.Kind;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.Location;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.OnMethod;

@BTrace
public class Simple {

  @OnMethod(
      clazz = "com.acme.Main",
      method = "main",
      location = @Location(Kind.ENTRY)
  )
  public static void mainEjbCall() {
    println("enter");
  }

}
```

*** Update ***

Yes, I assume it's a JBoss AS classloader issue but I don't know how to fix it.

I can profile normal Java 8 applications (even though I get an exception from the ASM ClassReader).

Comment: Interesting. I assume you have checked the JVM and visualvm are owned by the same user? If you're able to btrace other java8 programs, this might be the classloader separation of the AS getting in your way?